# Returning Promise.all from Function

Tags: javascript, promise

I am attempting to return a promise with Promise.all but for some reason my .then values are evaluating to undefined.  This seems to work when it's all inline but it was my understanding I should be able to return the top promise.all and then treat it like any other promise.

```
function createStreamerArray() {
  const regularStreamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]
  const baseURL = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api'

  return Promise.all(
    regularStreamers.map(streamer => {
      Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/users/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)),
        Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/streams/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)) 
      ]).then(values => {
        return values
      })
    })
  )
}

createStreamerArray().then(values => console.log(values))
```

Comment: for a start, you can remove the `.then(values => {
        return values
      })` - though, this wont fix any issue (but makes the code less incorrect :)

Comment: ADD `return` before the "inner" `Promise.all([` - so that your map actually returns something - or remove the `{}` that wraps the inner `Promise.all`

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then(values => {
        return values
      })`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly (and most importantly) you need to return a value in the `.map` callback

THis can either be done like this

```
regularStreamers.map(streamer => {
  // added return
  return Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/users/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)),
    Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/streams/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)) 
  ])
})
```

Or, using the short form for arrow functions, like this

```
//                               { removed
regularStreamers.map(streamer => 
  Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/users/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)),
    Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/streams/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)) 
  ])
)
// } removed
```

Secondly, (purely to remove unrequired code) remove the redundant

```
.then(values => {
    return values
})
```

This results in:

```js
    function createStreamerArray() {
        const regularStreamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
        const baseURL = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api';
      
        return Promise.all(regularStreamers.map(streamer => Promise.all([
              Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/users/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)),
              Promise.resolve($.getJSON(baseURL + '/streams/' + streamer + '?callback=?', null)) 
        ])));
    };
    createStreamerArray().then(values => console.log(values));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Which you will see, works

Comment: Works great, but that redundant code was in there as a placeholder. I don't actually want to return the values. I want to combine them into another object and return that but I was trying to get the rest working first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an extra return inside your map function? If you don't return the second Promise.all then you you won't see your values.