# difference between “Promise reject” with “try-catch”

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  try {
    throw new Error('test');
  } catch(e) {
    reject(e);
  }
});
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

we can use "try-catch" to throw error

```
// mothod 2
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject(new Error('test'));
});
promise.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

we also can use "reject" to throw error.

what's difference between them?

Comment: You [should never use `try`/`catch` inside a promise callback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42650428/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Exceptions thrown from asynchronous functions cannot be handled with try-catch block.
2. Promises are chain-able; prevents us from nesting code that affects readability.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective difference. In both cases, you're calling `reject()` with an error.

The following are also equivalent to what you have there:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('test');
});


var promise = Promise.reject(new Error('test'));


var promise = Promise.resolve().then(function () { throw new Error('test'); });
```