# Implementing coroutine control flow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, generator

The following implements a control flow wrapper `co` enabling asynchronous code to be delineated only by the `yield` keyword.

Is this basically what `async`/`await` does under the hood in ESwhatever?

```js
co(function*() {
    console.log('...');
    yield one();
    console.log('...');
    yield two();
})


function co(gFn) {
    var g = gFn();

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(go);

    function go() {        
        var result = g.next();
        if(result.done) {
            return;
        }
        if(isPromise(result.value)) {
            return result.value.then(go); // Promises block until resolution.
        }
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    }    
}

function isPromise(o) {
    return o instanceof Promise;
}

function one() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => (console.log('one'), resolve()), 1000));
}

function two() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => (console.log('two'), resolve()), 1000));
}
```

**Edit:**

In light of the responses I updated to take into consideration return values:

```js
co(function*() {
    console.log('...');
    const result1 = yield one();
    console.log('result1: ', result1);
    const result2 = yield two();
    console.log('result2: ', result2);
    const result3 = yield[one(), two()];
    console.log('result3: ', result3);
    const result4 = yield{
        one: one(),
        two: two()
    };
    console.log('result4: ', result4);
})

function co(gFn) {
    var g = gFn();

    return Promise.resolve().then(go);

    function go() {
        var result = g.next(...arguments);
        if (isPromise(result.value)) {
            return result.value.then(go);
        }
        if (Array.isArray(result.value)) {
            return Promise.all(result.value).then(go);
        }
        if (isObject(result.value)) {
            var o = {};
            var promises = Object.keys(result.value).map(k=>result.value[k].then(r=>o[k] = r));
            return Promise.all(promises).then(()=>o).then(go);
        }
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
}

function isPromise(o) {
    return o instanceof Promise;
}

function isObject(val) {
    return val && (Object === val.constructor);
}

function one() {
    return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>(console.log('one'),
    resolve('result 1')), 1000));
}

function two() {
    return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>(console.log('two'),
    resolve('result 2')), 1000));
}
```

Comment: _"Is this basically what `async/await` does under the hood in ESwhatever?"_ Is the inquiry solely to determine the equivalency of one approach to another approach?

Comment: Have you had a look under the covers of any transpilers to see how they achieve it?

Comment: @PhilCooper I have glanced at `co` source.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes.

Comment: Yes, you got the basic idea. But a) you pass the wrong arguments to `goFn` b) your `go` function doesn't `return result.value` c) you've never handled any promise errors (that should lead to `g.throw(…)`) d) `await` does not handle arrays or objects specially …and a few more smaller things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this basically what async/await does under the hood in ESwhatever?

Not really. It's a different approach for doing sorta the same thing. What `async/await` turn into is more like

```
async function foo() {
  const bar = await Bar();
  bar++;
  const baz = await Baz(bar);
  return baz;
}
```

becomes

```
function foo() {
  return Bar()
    .then(bar => {
      bar++;
      return Baz(bar)
        .then(baz => {
          return baz;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @Bergi But the code you added in your edit (`.then(baz => { return baz; })`) is a no-op.

Comment: And so is `const baz = …; return baz;` :-) [Apart from the additional resolve step it's useless indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41089205/1048572), but the translation of `async`/`await` is mechanical and you've placed a useless `await` in your code, so well…

Comment: @torazaburo, hey, can you also please extend your answer to include how the slightly modified example is translated into promises approach? This is the modified example: `const bar = await Bar(); someAsyncFn(); bar++;...`. Is it just executed alongside `bar++;` without any affects on promise chain?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, that's just a standard function call.

Comment: @Bergi, I got it, thanks. So I can assume that any call to a function without `await` doesn't add `.then` to a prototype chain?

Answer (score 3):

[Stage 3 Draft / January 26, 2016
Async Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) provides examples of three patterns; `Promise`; `Generator`; `Async Functions`; where the distinct approaches essentially produce the same result

> [Examples#](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#examples)
>
> Take the following example, first written using Promises. This code
>   chains a set of animations on an element, stopping when there is an
>   exception in an animation, and returning the value produced by the
>   final succesfully executed animation.
>
> ```
> function chainAnimationsPromise(elem, animations) {
>     let ret = null;
>     let p = currentPromise;
>     for(const anim of animations) {
>         p = p.then(function(val) {
>             ret = val;
>             return anim(elem);
>         })
>     }
>     return p.catch(function(e) {
>         /* ignore and keep going */
>     }).then(function() {
>         return ret;
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> Already with promises, the code is much improved from a straight callback style, where this sort of looping and exception handling is
>   challenging.
>
> Task.js and similar libraries offer a way to use generators to further
>   simplify the code maintaining the same meaning:
>
> ```
> function chainAnimationsGenerator(elem, animations) {
>     return spawn(function*() {
>         let ret = null;
>         try {
>             for(const anim of animations) {
>                 ret = yield anim(elem);
>             }
>         } catch(e) { /* ignore and keep going */ }
>         return ret;
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> This is a marked improvement. All of the promise boilerplate above and beyond the semantic content of the code is removed, and the
>   body of the inner function represents user intent. However, there is
>   an outer layer of boilerplate to wrap the code in an additional
>   generator function and pass it to a library to convert to a promise.
>   This layer needs to be repeated in every function that uses this
>   mechanism to produce a promise. This is so common in typical async
>   Javascript code, that there is value in removing the need for the
>   remaining boilerplate.
>
> With async functions, all the remaining boilerplate is removed,
>   leaving only the semantically meaningful code in the program text:
>
> ```
> async function chainAnimationsAsync(elem, animations) {
>     let ret = null;
>     try {
>         for(const anim of animations) {
>             ret = await anim(elem);
>         }
>     } catch(e) { /* ignore and keep going */ }
>     return ret;
> }
> ```