# Fetch react native get data out of the function

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch function that return the data like a classic function. like this :

```
function fetchGetData(idUser){
        fetch('url?idU='+idUser)
        .then((response)=>console.log(response))
        .then((responseText)=>{
            if(responseText.result!='true'){
                console.log(responseText)
             return parseInt(responseText) // return the data (a number for me)
            }
            else {
              return 0 ; 
            }
        });
    }
```

then I want to use the function like this : var data = fetchGetData(id);
I'm new on react, I don't know if its possible. In my context, i can't use states to save it in the function. Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Is expected response `JSON` or plain text?

Comment: Have you determined if response from server is `JSON` or plain text?

Comment: the response is plain text. i tried your code but it didnt works for me :(

Comment: Can you describe "didnt works"? Have you tried linked jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bvcdyj4k/?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to asgin response of the request to a vaiable like a sync function response (`var data = fetchGetData(id);`), It's better to use [async/await](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) for this case.
It's your rewritten fetchGetData:

```
async function fetchGetData(idUser){
  try {
    let response = await fetch('url?idU='+idUser);
    console.log(response);
    let responseText = await response; // are you sure it's not response.json();?
    if(responseText.result!='true'){
      console.log(responseText);
      return parseInt(responseText) // return the data (a number for me)
    } else {
      return 0 ; 
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Now you can assign it's returned value by calling the function:

```
var data = await fetchGetData(id);
```

In this way, you are using async actions link sync actions.

Comment: _"It's better to use async/await for this case."_ Can you define "better"? Is `response` a `javascript` object or text?

Comment: Better is because how response assigned (`var data = fetchGetData(id);`).

Comment: That is not the definition of "better". The approaches are functionally equivalent [Implementing coroutine control flow in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547606/implementing-coroutine-control-flow-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks for your responses, the fetch call a php function that return a number. I dont know what response type is, i just wanna get that number in a variable out of the fetch function. I can see it with a console log inside of the function but i cant outside

Comment: Note, the `responseText` cannot be a `javascript` object and plain text at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If expected response is `JSON`, chain `.json()` to `response` to return `javascript` object, else use `.text()` to return response as plain text

```
function fetchGetData(idUser) {
  return fetch('url?idU=' + idUser) // note `return` fetch from function call
    .then(response => {
      return response.text() // if `response` is `JSON` use `.json()` here
    })
    .then(responseText => {
    //  if (responseText.result != 'true') { // is expected response `JSON` or text?
        console.log(responseText);
        return parseInt(responseText) // return the data (a number for me)
    //  } else {
    //    return 0;
    //  }
    })
    .catch(err => Promise.reject(err))
}
```

Comment: thank's for your response, i want to return a number in this fonction, basically a text. my fetch call a php fonction that returns a number. i juste want to get that number.

Comment: `javascript` at Answer should return expected result https://jsfiddle.net/bvcdyj4k/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.. use `_bodyText` properties

```
function fetchGetData(idUser){
        fetch('url?idU='+idUser)
        .then((response)=>{console.log(response._bodyText)
              return parseInt(response._bodyText)})
        );
    }
```