# How does async function behaves when some of its inner async functions are called without await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm looking [at this article](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#you-dont-need-await-if-you-fire-and-forget) about `async/await`. It contains the following:

> Sometimes, you only want to trigger an asynchronous computation and
>   are not interested in when it is finished. The following code is an
>   example:
>
> ```
> async function asyncFunc() {
>     const writer = openFile('someFile.txt');
>     writer.write('hello'); // don’t wait
>     writer.write('world'); // don’t wait
>     await writer.close(); // wait for file to close
> }
> ```

I'm interested in how the function proceeds if there is no `await` for asynchronous functions calls insdide *in this particular case*. So can somebody please rewrite the above example using promises so I can better understand what's going on?

### EDIT

As I understand, it can be rewritten like this:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    const writer = openFile('someFile.txt');
    writer.write('hello'); // don’t wait
    writer.write('world'); // don’t wait

    return writer.close().then(()=>{

    });

}
```

Thanks

Comment: That example doesn't make much sense. How would you close the file before having completed writing? It should wait anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, thanks, maybe that's what confusing me. But still rewriting it with promises is possible, right? Can you maybe come up with a better example?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547745/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, I [added clarification comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547606/implementing-coroutine-control-flow-in-javascript/43547745#comment75407212_43547745) there. Take a look if you have time. Appreciate

Comment: @Bergi, is the way I rewrote the function correct? I added that to the question details

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    const writer = openFile('someFile.txt');
    writer.write('hello'); // don’t wait
    writer.write('world'); // don’t wait

    return writer.close();
}
```

ES2015:

```
function asyncFunc() {
    const writer = openFile('someFile.txt');
    writer.write('hello'); // don’t wait
    writer.write('world'); // don’t wait

    return writer.close();
}
```

assumption, is that writer.close(); always returns a promise, and the resolution value is not used by the caller.

Comment: yeah, I thought about simply `return writer.close();`, but I try to translate every `await` into `then`