# async js code using generators

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator

I need to proces some data. I can do it in sync and async way like this (simplified):

1. sync way:

   ```
   for (var i in input) {
       result += input[i]
   }
   ```
2. async way

   ```
   function f(input,cb) {
     var result;
     if (!input) {
       setTimeout(function() {cb(result)},500);
     } else {
       f(input.slice(1),function(r) {
         result+=input[0];
       });
     }
   }
   ```

Is it possible to rewrite async code using generators? I wish I had some For loop code instead of recursion.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't see a point in processing this data in asynchronous way, unless it takes a lot of time and you don't want to block the event loop. Also, in this example you could just use the `.join()` method: `result = input.join('');`.

Comment: By the way, your async code using callbacks is overcomplex. Doing input.slice(1) at each iteration is not a performant way...

Comment: @Michał Perłakowski. yeah, It is just an example. In reality, I'm fetching data asynchronously from Internet, I have no input[] array. I want to process async data but to avoid recursive callbacks - is it possible?

Comment: @user2106769 Yes, it's possible. Read about promises and async functions. But we can't help you without having some more specific example of your code.

Comment: _"Is it possible to rewrite async code using generators? I wish I had some For loop code instead of recursion."_ What is actual issue with code at Question?

Comment: @user2106769 if you think the existing answer works, can you mark this question as answered? if not, can you tell us what you want?

Comment: Although this question predates the other, appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101479/javascript-async-generator/52900682#52900682

Answer (score 0):

Using [await](https://certsimple.com/blog/javascript-equals-async-await) (a newer ES2017 technology that is [built on generators in ES6](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/870663432772608001)), and assuming, as you've said:

- you have multiple items (in this case `['apple', 'peach', 'banana']`)
- you wish to perform some async operation on them
- You wish to avoid callbacks and `.then()` (which is a good idea if you're on node 7+ or current browsers)

Then:

```
var doThing = async function (input) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(`Result for ${input}`)
        }, 2000);
    });
}


var start = async function(listOfThings){
    var result = await Promise.all(listOfThings.map(doThing))
    console.log('All done', result)
}

start(['apple', 'peach', 'banana'])
```

Will return:

```
All done [ 'Result for apple', 'Result for peach', 'Result for banana' ]
```

To get some data from the network instead, you can simply replace the the `setTimeout` with `superagent` or (if you want to write your own query string encoding, URL handling etc) `fetch`.

Comment: `async`/`await` does not use generators. It uses similar mechanisms, but is in no way based on them.

Comment: Thanks @bergi. I've edited my answer to clarify and add a reference to Eich's statement re: generators and await.

Comment: Why is `aync/await` usage necessary where `javascript` at Answer includes use of `Promise` constructor and `Promise.all()`?

Comment: See [Implementing coroutine control flow in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547606/implementing-coroutine-control-flow-in-javascript/43547825#43547825)

Comment: @guest271314 because without `await` you'd be using `.then()` and a callback to `.then()` for when the promise is resolved. `await` allows you to resume on the next line in the same style as traditional sync programming - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_style

Comment: The patterns are equivalent as to result. It is a matter of preference as to which pattern is utilized, no?

Comment: @guest271314 No, the `.then()` results in more complex code (it creates additional scopes) and achieves the result with longer code (which is inefficient).

Comment: @mikemaccana Interesting point about additional scopes. How can we empirically measure and compare the "efficiency" of each approach at https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/?

Comment: @guest271314 Cognitive overhead normally corresponds to the amount of tokens. Less functions equals less to understand.