# Javascript Async Generator

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is it possible to write an asynchronous generator like the following:

```
function gen() {
  return async function * () {
    yield await ...
    yield await ...
    yield await ...
  }()
}
```

So one can use it like this, for example:

```
for (let val of await gen()) {
  ...
}
```

I can't really work out the semantics of this construction, how are async generators used in loops?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is your goal?

Comment: No currently not. However, maybe in the future.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ppovoski To iterate over a bunch of operations that would otherwise be blocking, e.g. `fetch`

Comment: Redux-saga manages to do this by having a runtime function that handles the iterators. If the yielded value from the iterator is a promise, it will not call `.next()` or `.throw()` on the iterator until the promise has completed.

Comment: `fetch` isn't blocking.

Comment: You can consider changing your pattern to find and process one item at a time?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 of course, one solution is to just copy paste the routine whenever I need to iterate over it (which I ended up using), but that'd defeat the main goal of the question itself.

Comment: copy/paste?  those some fighting words :-)...definitely was misunderstood with my original post

Comment: @Ctznkane525 no, sorry, I don't mean to fight. What I meant is that yes, I am aware that I can change the pattern to circumvent the lack of this feature, and in fact I ended doing so by repeating the same for loop a couple times throughout my code instead of calling a generator

Comment: a little bit of kidding, just not a fan of copy/paste coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the async iteration proposal is complete, you could take a page from the Redux-saga book (like Cory Danielson mentioned) and have an adapter function that does all the async/await stuff.

```js
const later = async (delay, value) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay);
    });
};

function* rangePromise() {
    for (let i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        let nextValue = yield later(100, i);
        yield nextValue;
    }
}

const forEachAsyncAdapter = async (iterator, ...callbacks) => {
    try {
        let next = iterator.next();
        while (!next.done) {
            while (!next.done && next.value && next.value.then) {
                next = iterator.next(await next.value);
            }
            if (!next.done) {
                await callbacks.reduce(
                    async (nextValue, callback) => {
                        nextValue = await callback(await nextValue);
                        return nextValue;
                    },
                    Promise.resolve(next.value)
                );
                next = iterator.next();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (typeof iterator.return === 'function') {
            iterator.return();
        }
    }
};


forEachAsyncAdapter(
    rangePromise(),
    async i => { console.log(i); return Array(i).join('a'); },
    async s => { console.log(s); return s.toUpperCase(); },
    async s => { console.log(s); }
);
```