# Catching promise errors from a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to call multiple promises inside a for loop, but it gives me `unhandled promise exception` during each run. The way to solve this is to return the second promise, this way the last catch would be executed and it would work without errors, but - second and more iterations would not be executed.

```
const doFirstThing = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => (resolve(['a', 'b', 'c'])), 1000);
    });
}

const doSecondThing = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => (reject('test')), 500); // reject here
    });
}

doFirstThing()
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(result => {
        doSecondThing(result)
        .then(() => console.log(result, 'done'));
    });
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

How can I deal with this?

Comment: try putting a 'return' before your 'doSecondThing' and then the errors should flow up the then's, or so i believe.

Comment: Yes, but it would return from the first iteration...

Comment: yep youre right, use JQuery $.when or  Promise.all and use your loop to create an array of promises to pass in.

Comment: Yeah, have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all ?

Comment: [Never use `forEach` with (or without) promises!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `unhandled promise exception` chain `.catch()` to lat `.then()`; substitute using `Promise.all()` and `.map()` for `.forEach()`

```js
const doFirstThing = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => (resolve(['a', 'b', 'c'])), 1000);
    })
}

const doSecondThing = (r) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => (reject('test')), 500); // reject here
    })
}

doFirstThing()
.then(results => {
    return Promise.all(results.map(result => {
        return doSecondThing(result)
    }));
})
.then((result) => console.log(result, 'done'))
.catch(error => console.log(`err:${error}`));
```

Comment: `.catch(err => Promise.reject(err));` [makes no sense](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)