# Then is not a function promise error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm new to promises and I use the bluebird docs to get data from async code

what I tried is the following:

the error is:

> `getToken.then` is not a function

How can I avoid it?

This file connection.js

```
return connection.getToken.then(function(connToken){

   console.log(connToken);

}).catch({


})
```

This the code of getToken in moduleB

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const Promise = require("bluebird");
module.exports = {


    getToken: function () {


        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://authentication.arc.com/oauth/token',
                headers: {
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                    authorization: 'Q0MDdmMCFiMTc0fGNvlQVRDWThDNDFsdkhibGNTbz0=',
                    accept: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                form: {
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                    token_format: 'opaque&response_type=token'
                }
            };


            request(options)
                .then(function (body) {

                    return body;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return err;          
                });
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Aron - sorry update the question with the error...

Comment: Apart from the obvious typo (missing method call), avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and [Drop the pointless `.then(body => body)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to actually call the function.

**connection.js**

```
return connection.getToken() // note the parentheses ()
  .then(function(connToken){
    console.log(connToken);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Still Im not getting the data ....

Comment: are you still getting the same error?

Comment: No but the console log doesnt print the data ... so I guess I someing wrong in the promise in the getToken function, can you take a look please?

Comment: put a `console.log` or `console.error` in the `catch` handler too so you can see what's going on. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I dont get any erorr do you the cosole log are called before the I got the data from the promise, any idea why ? maybe the getToken was not using well promises ?

Comment: @JennyHilton You're not `resolve`ing your promise at any point. And neither should you, because you don't need a wrapping promise, since `request` already produces a promise.

Comment: @deceze - so can you please show me what I should fix in the gettoken function?

Comment: @Jenny `function getToken() { return request(...); }` - That is all you need.