# console.log returning pending promise, not actual data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, asynchronous

So I have this file:

```
 'use strict'
import * as moment from "moment";
import { Report} from "./Report";
import { Timeframe} from "./Timeframe";
import { ReportComparison } from "./ReportComparison";

function test(firstFrom: string, firstTo: string, secondFrom: string, secondTo: string) {


    var pastReport = new Report(new Timeframe(moment(firstFrom), moment(firstTo)));
    var laterReport = new Report(new Timeframe(moment(secondFrom), moment(secondTo)));

    var reportComparison

    function getData(pastReport: Report, laterReport: Report) {

        var later = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                laterReport.fetchData(data => resolve(data));
            });
        };

        var past = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                pastReport.fetchData(data => resolve(data));
            });
        };

        return Promise.all([later(), past()]).then(() => {
            laterReport.sort();
            reportComparison = new ReportComparison(pastReport, laterReport);

            return {
                pastReport: {
                    projects: reportComparison.pastReport.projects,
                    timeFrame: reportComparison.pastReport.timeframe,
                    totalAutomatedRuns: reportComparison.pastReport.totalAutomatedRuns,
                    totalManualRuns: reportComparison.pastReport.totalManualRuns

                },
                laterReport: {
                    projects: reportComparison.laterReport.projects,
                    timeFrame: reportComparison.laterReport.timeframe,
                    totalAutomatedRuns: reportComparison.laterReport.totalAutomatedRuns,
                    totalManualRuns: reportComparison.laterReport.totalManualRuns
                },
                trends: reportComparison.trends
            }

        });

    }

    return getData(pastReport, laterReport).then((res) => {
        return res;
    });

}



console.log(test("20170707", "20170707", "20170710", "20170710"))
```

Right now, the console.log returns `Promise { <pending> }` and not the actual value I want returned (the JSON object). Am I approaching this asynchronous code correctly? What solution could I use to return the JSON as a value, not a pending promise.

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then(res => res)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi FWIW there was an extra `console.log` in there originally - it was edited out for clarity

Answer (score 4):

The method *test* indeed returns a promise. To access the data, call the .then() function.

```
test("20170707", "20170707", "20170710", "20170710")
    .then((response) => {
         console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You will get promise only as you are returning promise from here

> return getData(pastReport, laterReport).then((res) => {
>
> ```
>     return res; //Do callback here...
> });
> ```

This is your main return I mean return value of test function and you have returned promise only and note that what you have returned from then it will be returned in that function only so it will not reflect in test's return value.
If you don't want to change your code you can use callback

or change it to

> return getData(pastReport, laterReport)

and make your test call like this

```
test(...).then((res)=>{ 
})
Or like this
var a = await test(...)
then test will return data.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve my problem. I want `test` to actually be the json object. Your solution just uses `then` to keep piping the information, never returning it

Comment: your get data will return it right??

Comment: I am returning promise by this call `return getData(pastReport, laterReport)` and then will fetch the json object so your json object will be in res

Comment: @adamSiwiec yes it does, you need to learn how to work with promises.  The data you want to return isn't available until the promise is fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, I understand @YashGanatra, but is there a way that test can hold that value and not res? That is my question.

Comment: use callback as I said

Comment: Or if you dont want to use then you can use await. I have edited my answer @adamSiwiec