# Tons of modules ship with console.log but they don't return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, return

I'm new to javascript and I find this very surprising as I come from python. All modules I've seen so far cover how their functions will work with console.log(output), but modifying the code to `return output` won't work at all as it's returning `undefined`. As an example, I'm including two such modules:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cryptocompare
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-coinmarketcap

As you can see, cryptocompare gives an example on the usage of their function:

```
cc.priceMulti('BTC', 'USD')
.then(prices => {
  console.log(prices)
  // -> { BTC: { USD: 1114.63 } }
})
```

Changing this code to:

```
cc.priceMulti('BTC', 'USD')
.then(prices => prices )
```

will now return undefined, whereas it was logging correct object before. I tried googling and searching for documentations for this, but I don't know a correct `query` that would describe this question. I found tons of modules that just support console.logging, but never indicate how do we make the objects tangible. I wonder why is this happening, because after all the reason we all want to use modules is to use their returned objects in one way or another, and not only print them right?
This is what returns undefined:
    const cc = require('cryptocompare')

```
function fetchPrices(){
cc.priceMulti(['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'DASH'], ['USD'])
.then(prices => prices)
}
console.log(fetchPrices())
```

Comment: `prices => { prices }` is a function that doesn't return anything.  What do you expect?

Comment: I tried both prices => prices and prices => {prices}. I'll edit my post. Isn't prices => prices supposed to be returning some value?

Comment: How do you know that your second example *returns* undefined? How do you check that? I'm asking since the promise based approach of `then` is asynchronous.

Comment: I'll include answer to that in the post.

Comment: [`.then(prices => prices)` is pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572), it just returns the same promise. Drop it. And learn how to use promises.

Comment: "*I found tons of modules that just support console.logging, but never indicate how do we make the objects tangible.*" - the console.log is just an example that you should replace by your own code. Which can use the `prices` inside that callback.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `fetchPrices()` function in your example. You might want to read up on promises.

Comment: It's like you are seeing documentation that gives the example `console.log(3 * 5)`, and you say that the multiplication operator only allows logging.

Comment: Except that return 3 * 5 would return 15 instead of undefined

Comment: Anyway can anyone answer how to write a code that would enable returning an object or point me to a right link? I searched resolving promises but I don't directly see their application here

Comment: https://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: You just need to use a return statement. You're currently not returning anything from fetchPrices. Just do this: `function fetchPrices(){ return cc.priceMulti(['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'DASH'], ['USD']); }`. Then `fetchPrices()` correctly returns a Promise, so the caller can do things like `fetchPrices().then( prices => { console.log( prices ); } )` or `const prices = await fetchPrices(); console.log( prices );`.

Comment: I just tried adapting the code from that link and the output is always Promise pending

Comment: `.then(prices => prices)` doesn't do anything so you can leave that off.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You could do `.then(prices => { console.log(prices); return prices; })`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function fetchPrices(){
  return cc.priceMulti(['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'DASH'], ['USD'])
}

async function main () {
  const result = await fetchPrices();
  console.log(result);
  // do things with result
}
main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: `.then()` never returns `undefined`.

Comment: Promise { <pending> } this is the output of `console.log(main())`

Comment: @Συλχαν: That's because it's async.  You need to learn how to write asynchronous code.

Comment: So almost all modules that are on npm require you to write additional line of codes to return some value?

Comment: Most the modules that are on npm use callbacks.  Only the newer ones use promises.  You can use promises without wrapping things up in async/await but it's easier to use async/await.