# How to store asynchronous data inside a variable Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I am working on a project that uses Laravel for back-end and React for front-end.

Whenever the user clicks login, a modal will open that will, up on submitting, fetch the users bearer token.

These fetch functions are all located inside `AuthService.js`

```
export function getLoginToken(email, password) {
    fetch("/api/login", {
        method: "post",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJSON) => {
        return responseJSON;
    })
}
```

The Nav component is where the login button resides, so I'm importing and using the funcionts that I've created inside `AuthService.js`

When I console log the json result **within** the actual getLoginToken function, there is no problem. Because up on placing it inside `.then()` it waits for it to complete so it doesn't result in undefined.

Now.. Inside the Nav component, there is an `onClick` function bound to the login button, which will execute `AuthService.getLoginToken(email, password)`

**Actual problem:**

I would like to store the response data inside a variable, but i keep getting undefined. This because I'm trying to insert asynchronous data inside a synchronous function.

I've also tried:

```
AuthService.getLoginToken(loginEmail, loginPassword).then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                token: result
            });
        });
```

But this will also return: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then((responseJSON) => {
        return responseJSON;
    })`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572) and instead put a `return` in the beginning of the `getLoginToken` function, so that you return the chained promise. Then you can use the syntax in your second snippet

Comment: You can’t do fetch in normal JavaScript function because fetch only works when a class extends the component. Also this won’t be available in normal JavaScript function until and unless you pass this as a param to the function

Comment: @Bergi will the fetch work in normal JavaScript function?

Comment: @Think-Twice Why wouldn't it? It's a function that can be called after all, from anywhere.

Comment: Ok what I thought was fetch is bound to the component but not a regular JavaScript function. Like component this won’t be available until we pass this from component to the function so I thought fetch also works in similar way

Comment: @Think-Twice [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @Alexander thanks for pointing me to the right path. My understanding was completely wrong I always thought fetch is a concept behind react but I never know it’s belongs to JavaScript. ThankQ I learned something new for the day :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
export function getLoginToken(email, password) {
  return fetch("/api/login", {
    method: "post",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': email,
        'password': password
    })
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => {
    return responseJSON;
})
}
```

Proper way would be to use state management tool like redux

Comment: I've implemented Flux as state management tool, I was planning on setting bearer tokens inside the `handleLogin` function. Is this the proper way?

Comment: please leave your comment while negative marking. I would also like to know what I was missing !!

Comment: @Regentix I haven't used flux, so cannot really say what would be the proper way. However does the solution work for you?

Answer (score -2):

You can use async await. Or use redux-thunk if you are doing redux.