# How do I chain promises and catch in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a new document based on the request received and here's what I'm trying to do.

```
var function = (req,callBack)=>{
    queryDB.findOne({query}).then((result)=>{
        return(result); // see if requested object exists in DB and return if yes  
}).then((result)=>{
    if(condition:if required object exists){
        updateDB.updateOne({query}).then((result)=>{ //update required object with new values
            if(condition:update successful){
                ref.function(value).then((k)=>{ // invoke for computation
                    return(k);
                }).then((k)=>{
                    var document = new Document({ //create a new document 
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
                    });

                    document.save().then((doc)={
                        callBack(doc); //return new document after successful insert
                    }).catch((err)=>{
                        updateDB.updateOne({query}).then((doc)=>{}) //revert back the update done earlier incase of error while inserting new document
                        callBack(err);
                    });
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    updateDB.updateOne({query}).then((doc)=>{}) //revert back the update done earlier incase of error when invoked function has an error (2)
                    callBack(err);
                })
            }
        }).catch((errorMessage)={
            callBack(errorMessage);
        })
    }else{
        callBack("Required Object Doesn't Exist");
    }
}).catch((errorMessage)=>{
    callBack(errorMessage);
})
```

}

The behavior I'm expecting is if there is an error in ref.function it should revert the update and send back error message but the API hangs indefinitely without reverting back the update done prior.

While the revert back works fine in-case of error in inserting new document to DB.

Comment: Do not use a `callBack`, return a promise instead. Try promise chaining to return a promise for the innermost result.

Comment: What exactly is `ref.function`, and what is the error in it that causes this behaviour?

Comment: @Bergi this function generates a unique ID based on certain criteria. this is a common to all API in the application I've deleted the file ref that has this function, simulating a case which might happen files being deleted/renamed and not updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I've deleted the file that has this function*"? If the function you try to call does not exists, that's an exception you cannot catch with promise `.catch()`, you will need a `try` block for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ref.function(value)` is followed by a `then` with `return k`, the `catch` block probably only catches the errors if `ref.function` rejects the promise and the errors in the block below (after `ref.function`)

```
.then((k)=>{ // invoke for computation
   return(k);
})
```

Try adding `Promise.resolve` before the `ref.function`

```
 return Promise.resolve(
 () => {
   return ref.function(value);
 }).then(
 k => {
    ...
 }).catch(
 err => {
    updateDB.updateOne({query}).then((doc)=>{}) //revert back the update done earlier incase of error when invoked function has an error (2)
    callBack(err);
 });
```

Comment: Why? Please explain what difference it would make.

Comment: @Bergi Since the `ref.function` is the first call, I think that the `catch` will only catch the errors that happens after that call. With the `success, error`, it should catch the error from your `ref.function`.

Comment: No change still keeps hanging.

Comment: @WilliamJuan Yeah, [I know the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572), but please put that explanation in your answer and why you think it caused the problems for the OP

Comment: @WilliamJuan Ah, now I see what you mean, but no that's wrong. `catch` can catch errors from anywhere as long that leads to the promise getting rejected. [`.then((k)=>{    return(k);
})` is a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572), but it still forwards rejections.