# How to wrap a try catch block inside an arrow function to call an api?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, promise, arrow-functions

I have an arrow function which returns some data from an api call. i want to wrap it up inside a try catch block like

```
const fetchEmployees = () => (
   try{
       fetch('http://localhost:6873/api/values', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
       })
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(names => { return names })
       } catch (error) {
           return error;
       }
  )
```

How could i do that? The perfectly working arrow function I have is

```
const fetchEmployees = () => (
fetch('http://localhost:6873/api/values', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(names => names )
)
```

Comment: Why not simply use `catch` on `fetch`?

Comment: What error are you trying to catch.  Failed .json()?

Comment: i am new to promise can you elaborate? @arfeo

Comment: yes something like that @chriss

Comment: Btw, [drop the pointless `.then(names => names)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)!

Comment: The *actual problem* is that you're using parentheses `()` not braces `{}` for the body of the arrow function - it only works in the second case because the body is a single expression. But also you should `.catch` a rejected promise.

Comment: Do you really want to `return error` from the `catch` block? That's not a good idea, you should *handle* the error there not sell it as a result.

Comment: actual error is that you cant use try catch on async process, I added response bellow, hope it will clarify what is happening

Comment: `'content-type': 'application/json'` is nonsense. You are making a GET request. There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake, but i got undefined as result with that approach. @jonrsharpe

Comment: thanks for the link @Bergi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use try catch on fetch because fetch is async while try catch is sync. Therefore your try catch will always pass. if we assume that you received response, and .json() fails, in second then first parameter is success function second one is fail function that executes when .json() fails

```
const fetchEmployees = () => (
  fetch('http://localhost:6873/api/values', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(names => names, error => "json failed" )
)

fetchEmployees().then(success => {}, error => {})
```

Like this when you call fetchEmployees in first function will be executed if everything succeed, otherwise second will execute with error response, in this case hard coded string "json failed"

Answer (score 2):

Turn your function into an `async` one:

```
const fetchEmployees = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:6873/api/values", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    const names = await response.json();

    return names;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use async/await

```js
const fetchEmployees = async () => {
   try {
       let response = await fetch('http://localhost:6873/api/values', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
       });
       let json = await response.json();   
       return json;    
   } catch (error) {
     return error
   }
}
```