# How do I store a promise object inside a variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I want to know how I can store a promise as an object inside a variable

### My Code

---

**Read and Write Functions**

```
async function storage(data, key) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(`${key}`, JSON.stringify(data));
}

async function read(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(`${key}`, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

**My object which is being stored and how I'm calling my functions**

```
let testing = {
    swipe1: {
        key: 1,
        text: "Swipe1Text changed",
    },
    swipe2: {
        key: "2",
        text: "Swipe2Text",
    },
};

storage(testing, "tasks@today");

// I'm able to console.log the following

let readStorageSwipes = read("tasks@today").then((result) => {
    return result;
});
console.log(readStorageSwipes.swipe1);
```

I'm using the [following library](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) if some reference is required, this is for a react native expo project

Comment: You're storing the promise just fine in the `readStorageSwipes` variable?

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then((result) => { return reslt; })`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572), though.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry I should have been clear, I want to store the promise as an object inside the variable

Comment: You *are* storing the promise, which is an object with `.then` and `.catch` and `finally` methods, in the variable. Do you mean you want to store the result of the promise, the object that it fulfills with, in the variable? Then you will need to wait for the promise, with `await` or `.then()`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: You mean waiting for the result? No, the `.then()` callback waits for the result and will be called when the promise is fulfilled, but the return value of the `.then()` call is another promise and *that*'s what you're storing in the `readStorageSwipes` variable.

Comment: @Bergi Can you write an answer describing how I can store the object returned by the promise in a variable

Comment: You already have such a variable, named `result`, available in the callback function. In general, it's a bad idea to try storing the result object in an outer-scope variable. What do you plan to use it for?

Comment: @Bergi that object contains the text and keys for a dynamic swipe able list. I wanted to store it inside a variable to make it easier to use everywhere.

Comment: Consider what to render while the object is still being loaded from the storage (not yet available). Since you're using react, you'll probably want to `useEffect` and `useState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store read promise, since you're returning a promise in read function, you can directly store promise by

```
readPromise = read("tasks@today");
```

`readPromise` variable will be a promise object

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear, I want to store that promise as an object inside a variable

Comment: perhaps you can explain what you're doing to do with the promise object. It is still not clear what you want to achieve.