# async resolves before try catch runs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this cloud function:

```
const initCompress = async () => {
  try {
    logger.log('This shows before the function terminated');
    await mkdirp('../../../xxxxx'); <<<< WHY IS IT NOT WAITING FOR THIS TO COMPLETE?
    logger.log('This shows after the function terminated');
    return { success: true };
  } catch (err) {
    ...
  } finally {
    ...
  }
};
export default initCompress;
```

It is executed via:

```
const main = async () => {
  exports.compressImage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    initCompress(data, context);
  });
}
```

The console log shows:

```
functions: Beginning execution of "compressImage"
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"This shows before the function terminated"}
functions: Finished "compressImage" in ~1s
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"This shows after the function terminated"}
```

I'm probably doing something silly, but what? Do I need to await something somewhere?

Comment: Show us the logger, because if the logger, internally, uses promises (to prevent slowing down the main thread), it would actually show after the main promise would finish.

Comment: What exactly is unexpected/wrong with your console output? And what is `compressImage`  - you haven't shown that code? What is logging these lines that begin with `functions: …`?

Comment: @Bergi `compressImage` is a cloud function. I expected the logs to show before the function terminated.

Comment: @Akxe good point, I'll check the logger.

Comment: @Ben And what does `compressImage` have to do with `modifyImage`?

Comment: @Bergi `compressImage` executes `modifyImage`. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: @Ben Neither `initCompress` nor the `onCall` callback do `return` the promise, so `compressImage` won't know what to wait for. I would recommend to avoid mixing `.then()` syntax with `async`/`await`. [Drop the pointless `.then((response) => { return response; })`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi please have a look at the updated question. I simplified the code. Dropped the then catch. Still not able to get `initCompress` to wait for `mkdirp`

Comment: @Ben The function passed to `functions.https.onCall` still doesn't return anything to wait for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe is totally normal. By declaring a function as `async`, your make it `return` a `Promise`. That `Promise` is being returned immediately (it just doesn't resolve immediately). Your code is equivalent of this:

```js
const mkdirp = () => Promise.resolve();
const logger = console;

const modifyImage = () => {
  logger.log('This shows before the function terminated');
  return mkdirp('../../../xxxxx')
    .then(() => logger.log('This shows after the function terminated'))
    .then(() => ({ success: true }))
    .catch(logger.error);
};

modifyImage().then(logger.log);
logger.log('Function finished');
```

As a conclusion, never forget that `async`/`await` is just syntaxic sugar over Promises

Comment: I understand that mkdirp is an async function, so I guess my question is how to contain async functions inside a main function that only terminates once all async functions in it completed. I need to let the client know when it all finished, or when something failed. For now, I can only inform the function fired.

Comment: As you are using an asynchronous function, your "client" has to handle asynchronism either with a callback or with a promise. What is it exactly?

Comment: I simplified my async function even more. Please have a look at my question I tried everything - try catch, only then and catch. I am unable to execute initCompress and wait for the final response.

Comment: Have you tried to simply `return initCompress(data, context);`? Firebase's `functions.https.onCall` accepts `Promise<any>` as return value

Comment: Yes. That's was it. I knew it was something silly that I did. Thank you!