# how to return values from JS .then function [using arrow function]

Tags: javascript, return-value, arrow-functions

Unsure how to access the values **date** and **prices** else where in the script

```
fetch("fileName")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    var date  = data.JSONdata[data.JSONdata.length - 1].date
    var prices = data.JSONdata[data.JSONdata.length - 1].prices
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Not "elsewhere". You can only access them in that `then` callback. Place your code that uses `date` and `prices` right after their `var` declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rewrite your code to use `async/await`:

```
const response = await fetch("fileName");
const data = await response.json();
const date  = data.JSONdata[data.JSONdata.length - 1].date;
const prices = data.JSONdata[data.JSONdata.length - 1].prices;
```

**EDIT:** To use this asynchronous code, you have to define the function in which you use this code as async:

```
async function yourFunction() {
    // your async code from above
}

// await async function where it's called
const functionResult = await yourFunction();
```

You have to make every function in your callstack async up to the level where you no longer care about the response. So the function which calls "yourFunction()" has to be async aswell. And so on.

Comment: when i do this i get the error message:  Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Please have a look at my edit @logan9997

Answer (score 0):

You can use await to get the Promise result. Please refer [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

In the given example date and prices are hard-coded which will be fetched via API calls in real-scenario

```
const date = Date.now();
const prices = [1000, 2000];
const resolvedProm = Promise.resolve({date, prices});

let thenProm = resolvedProm.then(({date, prices}) => {
    return {date, prices};
});

let res = await thenProm;
console.log(res); 
// {date: 1641136463085, prices: Array(2)}
```

Comment: `.then(({date, prices}) => { return {date, prices}; });` is pretty pointless

Comment: @Bergi Please enlighten me here, what seems off to you?

Comment: [It's just a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572). You can equivalently write `const thenProm = resolvedProm;` and it'll work the same.

Comment: **In the given example date and prices are hard-coded which will be fetched via API calls in real-scenario**