# Node.js combining await/async with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I connect to a Postgres database in Node and I get a return value from the database. However, when I try to pass that value to another function, the value is `undefined`. Check out this code:

```
async function doDbCall(queryString) {
    await client.connect()
        .then(async () => {
            await client.query(queryString)
                .then(dbRes => {
                    console.log("dbDoCall - dbRes", dbRes.rows[0]);
                    return dbRes;
                })
        });
}
```

Here is the calling function:

```
async function testTheDb() {
    try {
        const myReturnVal = await dbConn.doDbCall("SELECT NOW() as now");
        console.log("db val:", myReturnVal);
    }
    catch(ex) {
        console.log("db err", ex.message);
    }
}
```

In the console.log in `doDbCall()` on the query.then success, I get a value in dbRes.rows[0]. The console.log shows `dbDoCall - dbRes { now: 2022-09-26T16:47:14.465Z }`. So I return that value.

However, in the `testTheDb()` function, I have another console log where I log the value of `myReturnVal`. The result of that log shows `db val: undefined`.

My question is this: **Why is `myReturnVal` null in testTheDb()?**

Comment: `.catch(ex => { throw ex; })` is as [pointless as `.then(value => value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [should not mix `async`/`await` syntax with `.then()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385676/whats-wrong-with-awaiting-a-promise-chain). Your problem is that neither the `doDbCall` function nor the `async () => {…}` callback do return anything, your only `return` keyword is nested inside a nested `then` callback.

You should write either

```
function doDbCall(queryString) {
    return client.connect()
        .then(() => {
            return client.query(queryString);
        })
        .then(dbRes => {
            console.log("dbDoCall - dbRes", dbRes.rows[0]);
            return dbRes;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            client.end();
        });
}
```

or

```
async function doDbCall(queryString) {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        const dbRes = await client.query(queryString);
        console.log("dbDoCall - dbRes", dbRes.rows[0]);
        return dbRes;
    } finally {
        client.end();
    }
}
```