# React JS: Promise pending in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

In my React JS project, I have a **RequireAuth.js** which is used to check if the user is authorized every time they change pages.
As an example, inside the const "confirmToken", I'm calling an async function that returns `true` if the user's token is valid or `false`.

```js
const confirmToken = async () => {
    return await check();
  };

var v = confirmToken().then((result) => {
    return result;
});
```

It's working. But the variable `v` is returning as `Promise`.

```
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined}
```

I've checked other similar questions on Stack, but I still don't know what I'm getting wrong here.
Is there no way to return the boolean in a new variable?
My code is like this. The `allowedRoles` is a list of user levels that are passed in the route with RequireAuth.

```js
const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  try {
    var t = UseToken();
    var l = UseLevel();
  } catch (error) {
    return <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
  
  const confirmToken = async () => {
    return await checkToken(t);
  };

  var v = confirmToken().then((result) => {
    return result;
  });

  return v & (l in allowedRoles) ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : v ? (
    <Navigate to="/noAuthorized" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />
  );
};
```

*Obs: I am probably doing something really wrong here.*

I need it to return a boolean so that the ternary works in the `return()`.

Comment: [That `.then((result) => { return result; })` is pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Any async function will always return a Promise, change your code to:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState<string|undefined>()

useEffect(() => {
    confirmToken().then((result) => {
        setToken(result);
    });
}, []);

if(token) {
    if(l in allowedRoles) {
         return (<Outlet />);
    } else {
        return (<Navigate to="/noAuthorized" state={{ from: location }} replace />);
    }
}

return (<Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />);
```

Comment: Why not just `const result = await confirmToken()`?

Comment: @Andy because it conflicts with another part of the code. I wish there was another solution but meh.

Comment: Code updated, to use useEffect to fetch the token, and update a state var on promise resolution.

Comment: I didn't spot what the `confirmToken` function was doing. You could even do `const result = checkToken(t)` to save you using that intermediate function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform asynchronous logic, you will need to use `async`/`await` like so.

**Note:** I created a `sleep` function that waits for a set duration to mimic a network call.

```js
const ADMIN_TOKEN = '000-000';

const sleep = async (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const check = async (token) =>
  sleep(2000).then(() => token === ADMIN_TOKEN);

const config = { token: '000-000' };

const confirmToken = async () => check(config.token);

console.log('Waiting 2 seconds for the check to pass...');

(async () => {
  const result = await confirmToken();
  
  console.log(result);
})();
```

The `check` function can also be written as:

```js
const check = async (token) => {
  await sleep(2000);
  return token === ADMIN_TOKEN;
};
```

### React example

If you want to do this in React, you will need to combine an asynchronous IIFE with a `useEffect`:

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-async-useeffect-sdjjyo?file=/src/App.jsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ADMIN_TOKEN = "000-000";

const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const check = async (token) => sleep(2000).then(() => token === ADMIN_TOKEN);

const config = { token: "000-000" };

const confirmToken = async () => check(config.token);

const App = () => {
  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = useState(null);

  // Asynchronous effect
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const confirmed = await confirmToken();
      setAuthorized(confirmed);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span data-authorized={authorized ?? ""}>
        {authorized == null
          ? "Confirming..."
          : authorized
            ? "Authorized"
            : "Unauthorized"}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: the ```const result``` is not accessible outside the async. the thing is, how can i access it?

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco see my example that I included at the bottom.