# How can i use promises to get the value

Tags: javascript, promise

I have tried this but gives me a promise
I just want do it like this.

```js
function doSome() {
  return new Promise(
    function(res, rej) {
      let d = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        d.push(i)
      }
      res(d)
    })

}
console.log(doSome().then((val)=>{return val}));
```

Comment: Your function is returning a promise.  You must use either `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the resolved value of the promise.  I hope you realize that a promise is not necessary at all here because there is no asynchronous code.  You could  just return `d` directly without using a promise.  A promise is only helpful when you want to be notified when an asynchronous operation has completed.  Your `for` loop is entirely  synchronous and thus has no benefit from using a promise - in fact the promise just makes the code more complicated than necessary to use.

Comment: Just *don't* use promises and you'll get the actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use await. Because promise is a async

```
function doSome() {
    return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
        let d = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        d.push(i)
        }
        resolve(d)         
    });
}

//way to main function
async function main() {
    console.log(await doSome());
}
main();

//directly
(async () => {
    console.log(await doSome());    
})();
```

Comment: Your `.then()` handler here is pointless and not necessary.  `await`, all by itself, will get the value.

Comment: @jfriend00 ty. Correct but I didn't want to disrupt his code. I fixed it :)

Comment: Got an error that "missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @JohnDelvin you can try again.

Answer (score 2):

The provided code will not print the expected output because you're trying to `console.log()` the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) itself rather than its value. Since `console.log()` is **synchronous**, and Promise has an **asynchronous** nature, the issue can be solved by moving the logging into `.then` block:

```js
function doSome() {
  return new Promise(
    function(res, rej) {
      let d = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        d.push(i)
      }
      res(d)
    })

}

doSome()
  .then((val) => { return val })
  .then((val) => {
    // Do something
    console.log(val);
  });
```

Comment: Also [drop the pointless `.then(value => value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)!

Comment: I am thinking this answer is wrong.
Your question answer looks like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/9309919

anyway, your choice :)

Comment: @MuratÇakmak The thing that looks like a synchronous `sleep` is the part of the code taken from the OP. Your own answer has the very same problem.