# Do I have to use try catch or then catch when using async await to fetch data

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, try-catch

I am using `fetch` and `async await` to fetch data:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);
  const json = response.json();
  return json;
};

try {
  getData().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log('There was an error', error);
}
```

Do I have to use like above `try catch` or `then catch`?

**Update:**
Thanks to @bergi's answer:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);
  const json = response.json();
  return json;
};

    try {
      const result = await getData().then((data) => data);
      res.redirect(`/my-page/?id=${result.data.page.content.id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
```

Is this a clean and working approach?

Comment: You can use `try` only when you `await` the promise, which you didn't

Comment: @Bergi you mean I have to add `await getData()`? But is above a clean solution or is there a better syntax?

Comment: Yes, `try { const result = await getData(); console.log(result); } catch(err) { console.error(err); }` would work. The code you currently have in your question does not work.

Comment: @Bergi I added it to my question. Is that like you mean or can it be optimised?

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then((data) => data)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572), otherwise it's fine

Answer (score -1):

try {
console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);`enter code here`
}

You can do something like this fetch the response try with successful response and fail with catch if there is some error.