# Is there any purpose to wrapping an async function in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous-javascript

I'm just inherited a new codebase and this pattern in javascript seems to do nothing:

```
/**
 * Update Data Model
 * @param {Object} model
 * @param {String} field
 * @param {Mixed} value
 */
function updateDataModel(model, field, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    async function promiseFunc() {
      model[field] = value;
      await model.save();
      resolve(model);
    }

    return promiseFunc();
  });
}

module.exports = updateDataModel;
```

It's everywhere in the code base and I'm trying to be charitable, but I can't imagine any use of wrapping the async await within the promise? It's confusing and doesn't seem to do anything.

In my mind the above code pattern is basically equivalent to either:

```
/**
 * Update Data Model
 * @param {Object} model
 * @param {String} field
 * @param {Mixed} value
 */
async function updateDataModel(model, field, value) {
      model[field] = value;
      await model.save();
      return model
}

module.exports = updateDataModel;
```

---or---

```
/**
 * Update Data Model
 * @param {Object} model
 * @param {String} field
 * @param {Mixed} value
 */
function updateDataModel(model, field, value) {
      model[field] = value;
      const newModel = model.save().then((model)=> return model);
      return newModel;
}

module.exports = updateDataModel;
```

Am I missing something important here? Everything is very buggy and moving to a simpler pattern is one of the first steps the team is taking to try and improve. Error checking i somewhat difficult because the error is an unhandled promise in most cases.

Comment: Regarding the second snippet you suggested, [drop the pointless `.then((model)=> return model)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572). You don't need that if the promise returned by `.save()` already fulfills with the model. You may need `return model.save().then(() => model)` if it doesn't. But really, just go with `async`/`await`, it's easier to write, read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Since `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar around a Promise, the existing code is redundant and can be rewritten like you suggest.

> Each time when an async function is called, it returns a new Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception uncaught within the async function.

[Source: mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description)

Comment: Thank you so much that was my assumption! Seeing the pattern so much I was really trying to wrack my head around some sort of edge case before I equated to a misunderstanding of how javascript works.

Answer (score 1):

If the `save` promise returns the updated model, I would just return it.

```js
/**
 * Update Data Model
 * @param {Object} model
 * @param {String} field
 * @param {Mixed} value
 */
function updateDataModel(model, field, value) {
  model[field] = value;
  return model.save(); // Return the promise here (returns the underlying model)
}

const animal = {
  type: 'cat',
  color: 'white',
  save() {
    // Do some DB updates...
    return Promise.resolve(this);
  },
  toString() {
    return `Model(type=${this.type},color=${this.color})`;
  }
};

updateDataModel(animal, 'color', 'black').then(model => {
  console.log('Updated model:', model.toString());
});
```

Or:

```js
const model = await updateDataModel(animal, 'color', 'black');
console.log('Updated model:', model.toString());
```

Comment: Ha this is much better thank you! A little lost in the sauce here.

Answer (score 1):

> It's confusing and doesn't seem to do anything.

It actually does something: it's swallowing errors. This is utterly broken. Do not use it.

It would "work" if it was at least written as

```
function updateDataModel(model, field, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    async function promiseFunc() {
      model[field] = value;
      await model.save();
      return model;
    }

    resolve(promiseFunc()); // or `promiseFunc().then(resolve, reject)
  });
}
```

What you inherited is just another form of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). Avoid it at all costs! Definitely go for the much simpler approach you suggested.

Comment: This. Like my colleage who use `async void` in C# instead of `async Task` not in case that `async void` is needed, just because Exception wouldn't bubble up.

Comment: @LukeVo I very much doubt that it was done by purpose here, though