# Running node child processes asynchronously in a loop and receiving stdout results after loop ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stdout, child-process

I have the following sample code...

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const Main = async () => {
    const ret = await GetAllItems();

    console.log('results', ret);
};

const GetAllItems = async () => {
    const promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        promises.push(GetItem(i));
    }

        console.log('=== Loop ended ===')

    return await Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        return values;
    });
};

const GetItem = async (item = '') => {
    console.log('Getting data:', item);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec('echo', [item], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            // console.log(stdout);
            console.log('Receiving Data: ' + item);
            resolve('Receiving Data: ' + item);
        });
    });
};

Main();
```

And this is the result I'm getting...

```
Getting data: 0
Getting data: 1
Getting data: 2
Getting data: 3
Getting data: 4
Getting data: 5
Getting data: 6
Getting data: 7
Getting data: 8
Getting data: 9
Getting data: 10
Getting data: 11
Getting data: 12
Getting data: 13
Getting data: 14
=== Loop ended ===
Receiving Data: 12
Receiving Data: 11
Receiving Data: 10
Receiving Data: 9
Receiving Data: 8
Receiving Data: 7
Receiving Data: 6
Receiving Data: 5
Receiving Data: 4
Receiving Data: 3
Receiving Data: 2
Receiving Data: 1
Receiving Data: 0
Receiving Data: 14
Receiving Data: 13
```

So my question is, how come I'm receiving data only after the loop ends? any idea why it's in that specific order?

Ideally I'd like to receive the data as soon as the command is executed (before the loop ends), is this even possible?

Thanks for the help!

=====================

Comment: [Drop the pointless `.then((values) => { return values; })`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)

Comment: "*how come I'm receiving data only after the loop ends?*" - uh, because the events are not processed until you've created all your promises in the loop? "*any idea why it's in that specific order?*" - no, it's completely arbitrary. "*I'd like to receive the data as soon as the command is executed*" - you do, actually. It's just that your loop is faster than the command execution.

Comment: "*before the loop ends*" - do you actually want to process all the commands **sequentially**? Then put the `await` inside the loop, and don't use `Promise.all` or an array of promises!

Comment: Hi Bertín, thanks for your reply, I’m new to this to just trying to figure out what’s possible. 
- the loop is not faster, if you loop it 100 times you will see the same behaviour, data received after the loop finishes.
- I don’t want the results sequentially, I want to have the data as soon as the command runs. This is why I don’t await inside the loop.

Comment: - the promise.all is just to know when everything has been processed. I was expecting to see received data before the loop ends, is this possible?

Comment: No. If you don't wait for it inside the loop (run everything sequentially), you will not get (all) the data before the loop ends. If you run the loop only to kick off the asynchronous tasks (processing concurrently), that loop will always run to completion first, and only afterwards you will see the received data. **Why** would you want to see the data before the loop ends?

Comment: So this is just an example of what I’m trying to do, instead of echo, in reality it’s data processing. The idea is to kickstart all data processing in different threads rather than sequentially which would be slower. But seems like any approach I take doesn’t let me do what I want. I though running this “asynchronously” would let me do it and the reason for my confusion

Comment: The reason I want to see the data before the loop finishes if because I want to do more stuff with it. Or at least acknowledge that it has been processed (imagine doing 1000 loops) . But now I need to wait for the loop to finish to even process anything.

Comment: "*kickstart all data processing in different threads*" - you are doing that by creating separate OS processes (using `exec`)! Even if that's just an `echo` command, it comes with a lot of overhead and takes much longer than the loop. But even if it were faster, there are no separate threads for executing javascript. You wouldn't *want* to have all those `console.log` statements run at the same time and interrupt each other, it would lead to a total mess in the output.

Comment: "*now I need to wait for the loop to finish to even process anything*" - no. The data processing starts immediately. It's only the handling of the results that will need to wait for the loop. This is what **asynchronous** means. Try this with some commands that actually take a bit of time, and print timestamps with your outputs, to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: Hi Bergi, after a bit of digging I believe that worker threads is what Im after. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure, you're already using `child_process`. Do you mean using worker threads *instead* of that or *in addition* to that? Don't do the latter. What kind of processing do you actually want to do?

Answer (score -1):

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
const { exec } = require('child_process')

class ItemGetter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.on('item', item => this.handleItem(item));
  }

  handleItem (item) {
    console.log('Receiving Data: ' + item);
  }

  getAllItems () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      this
        .getItem(i)
        .then(item => this.emit('item', item))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
    console.log('=== Loop ended ===')
  }

  async getItem (item = '') {
    console.log('Getting data:', item);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec('echo', [item], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
        resolve(item);
      });
    });
  }
}

(new ItemGetter()).getAllItems()
```

You logic, for first, run loop with calling all GetItem, then output '=== Loop ended ===', and only after that run all promices resolution, so, if you want get result of each getItem execution independently of eachother, just don't abuse asynchronous logic, frequently right solution much simpliest, than it seems ;)

Note: in this solution, you will get the same output, because loop with getItem calling, runnung faster, then promises with exec, but in this case, each item will be handled exactly after appropriate promise will be resolved, except of awaiting of all promises resolution. But in case, when you whant to make method getAllItems, asyncronous too, and await, when all results will be handled, but still remaining each promise running independently, you should implement you own logic, eg, using counter of started getItem methods, which increments in a loop and decrements on each promise resolution, so, this can be not so trivial. From other side, when you starts getItems in a loop sincronuosly, its have a sence to leave using promise.all (or even promise.allSettled, depeding on you needs), and then handle all results also sincronously.

UPD: By the way, you should understand, how event loop works, and how its supply async behavior: code in the node.js run in one sequence, step by step syncronously, from start to end, in continuos loop. Any async operations, by fact just a sheduled for execution on next loop, if all conditions for start that code mutched (eg promise is resolved). Read [about event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick#understanding-processnexttick) for detailes. You can start parallel sequences in a child processes, for examle, using fork, or cluster, but each thread also will run syncronuosly in its own event loop.

Comment: Why introduce a `class` and an `EventEmitter`?

Comment: Just as example, yes, you can use class, but just a calling method, instead emit event, or even you can implemet everithing in functional style, or use prototypes, or ..., this is no matter, but if you more carefully read a text part of my comment, I hope you will understand, what I mean.

Comment: Usually I use event emitter pattern, because this pattern is very convenient for me and conceptually, in essence, reflects the event loop, which is generally the basis of the concept of asynchronous code. But I do not insist on using approach with class, or EventEmitter, citing it just as one of the possible solutions in this situation